# Alternative to popUntil in go router in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigator, flutter-go-router

I was wonder if there is alternative to Navigator's `popUntil()` method, or any workaround to achieve the same.

If i were to use `Navigator`. I would use like so:

```
void _logout() {
  Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/login'));
}
```

How to achieve the same in `go router` ?

---

I see a github issue - [[go_router] Implement popUntil #2728](https://github.com/flutter/packages/pull/2728), but there is no positive outcome of the same.

Comment: Do you mean you want to go to the `login` route, remove all routes below it and keep routes above it (if any)?

Comment: @PeterKoltai, I mean if you see navigation as a stack I want to pop everything till `login` and anything below it remains as is

Comment: Simply using `context.goNamed('/login')` does not work in this case? If there are routes which are not included in `/login` named route, they will be removed from the stack.

Answer (score 12):

---

**WORKAROUND**

---

While the answer from @CommonSense works, maybe we could tweak it a little, avoiding pop when GoRouter cannot pop.

And have [this in mind](https://github.com/flutter/packages/pull/2728/files#r1050607006). At the end, this is just a workaround and can leave to unexpected behaviors, specially with GoRouter upgrades in the future.

```dart
void popUntilPath(String routePath) {
    
  final router = GoRouter.of(context);
  while (router.location != routePath) {

    if (!router.canPop()) {
      return;
    }

    debugPrint('Popping ${router.location}');
    router.pop();
  }
}
```

---

**THE RIGHT WAY?**

---

Another way to do that (which seems to be the right way of doing this) is to use `.go` with the correct route declaration, like this:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Go Router Demo',
      routerConfig: GoRouter(
        initialLocation: '/login',
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            name: '/login',
            path: '/login',
            builder: (_, __) => const Login(),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                name: 'step-1',
                path: 'step-1',
                builder: (_, __) => const Step1(),
              ),
              GoRoute(
                name: 'step-2',
                path: 'step-2',
                builder: (_, __) => const Step2(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Entry Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Login entry page'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => GoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('step-1'),
              child: const Text('Go to step 1'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Step1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Step1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Step 1')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Step 1'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => GoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('step-2'),
              child: const Text('Go to step 2'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Step2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Step2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Step 2')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Step 2'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => GoRouter.of(context).goNamed('/login'),
              child: const Text('Go to login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you call `goNamed` to `/login`, it will do a pop until login, which is what you want.

If you don't declare you routes like this (maybe you are using the imperative API) the GoRouter will `go` to that route but by adding it into the stack and not just removing the other routes.

Comment: I can confirm: I tried "the right way" and it works exactly as expected! Thanks!

Comment: That being said, your workaround can be more convenient in complex navigation.

Answer (score 6):

go_router: 10.2.0

```
///Navigate back to specific route
void popUntilPath(BuildContext context, String routePath) {
 while (
  router.routerDelegate.currentConfiguration.matches.last.matchedLocation !=
      routePath) {
  if (!context.canPop()) {
  return;
  }
 context.pop();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps

```dart
while (GoRouter.of(context).location != "/") {
    debugPrint(GoRouter.of(context).location.toString()); //to get the routes in between
    GoRouter.of(context).pop();
}
```

Comment: it works, but sometimes it seems that you can see the pages being popped

Comment: [Acacio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2512732/ac%c3%a1cio-veit-schneider) You can use material or other transition for that.

Comment: yes, but then you would also need to change the transition for push, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. What you are looking for might have been a bug in older version of GoRouter but it's fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/123875). If you still feel there is some pop transition issue, you can open a fix request issue in it and we will look into it.

Comment: @CommonSense This doesn't work anymore in GoRouter v.10

Answer (score 1):

Tested this solution with `go_router: ^9.0.1`

Create a class and extend `NavigatorObserver`.

```
class MyNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  static List<String> backStack = [];

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    backStack.add(route.settings.name ?? '');
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    backStack.removeLast();
  }
}
```

Pass the observer while initiating GoRouter

```
GoRouter(
  initialLocation: initialLocation,
  observers: [ MyNavigatorObserver() ],
  ...
  ...
)
```

Use this function to pop until your desired route

```
void popUntil(String routeName) {
  if (!MyNavigatorObserver.backStack.contains(routeName))
      return;

  while (MyNavigatorObserver.backStack.last != RouteNames.bottomNav) {
    GoRouter.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following extension to achieve this.

```
extension GoRouterExtension on GoRouter {
  // Navigate back to a specific route
  void popUntilPath(BuildContext context, String ancestorPath) {
    while (routerDelegate.currentConfiguration.matches.last.matchedLocation !=
        ancestorPath) {
      if (!context.canPop()) {
        return;
      }
      context.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

The caller will be something like this:

```
GoRouter.of(context).popUntilPath(context, desiredAncestorPath);
```