# How to clear the backstack of pages?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I am looking for a way to pop backstack of pages in a Flutter app until home page is reached using [Go Router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router); something like an equivalent function of [popUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html) in Navigator.

```
navigatorKey.currentState?.popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```

I have tried 'hacks' like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77215775/6393618) to pop manually but the process of popping several pages on a loop is very visible on the screen and it looks like a glitch. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score -1):

So in this issue you can try bellow steps for solve your issue,

1.First you should setup `GoRouter` , you wank make a instance withing your app, assigning `navigatorKey` it can be use for navigation parts,    final

```
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

and look at full updated code segment as help,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerDelegate: GoRouter(
        initialLocation: '/',
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: '/',
            builder: (context, state) => MyHomePage(),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
      routeInformationParser: GoRouterInformationParser(),
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
  }
}
```

and you should use logic for navigate,

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to the home route ('/') using GoRouter
            GoRouter.of(context).goBackTo('/', refresh: true);
          },
          child: Text('If you want back to Home'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i cant find the 'goBackTo' function in GoRouter and i am using its latest version (v12.1.3). I tried this solution here and "the right way" seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76382101/6393618