How to preserve state in go_router, how to use keys properly and how to achieve a popuntil in the correct way?
I have this page structure (or i want to have this structure):
  welcome
  ├── login
  └── createaccount
      └── simpleimageeditor
          ├── mycropeditor
          └── myfiltereditor

I have 2 goals with this.
when I am done with my filter editor page I want to do context.go("createaccount") and it should pop mysimpleimageeditor, mycropeditor and myfiltereditor and it should mantain welcome and createaccount pages!
when I go back to createaccount it should have the createaccount page with its state preserved! I noticed in earlier tests that when i do context.go("createaccount") it returns to that page but it loses the state! in order to preserve state i have to always use statefulshellroute.indexedstack?
additionally if someone can explain to me the logic of the keys, when to use parentkeys and which ones to use and when to use keys in general I am having big trouble making the right logic
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> rootNavigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> createAccountNavigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'createAccount');

  class AppRouter {
    final AuthBloc authBloc = locator.get<AuthBloc>();
    late final GoRouter routes;
    static GlobalKey<CustomRefreshIndicatorState> clubhubRefreshKey =
        GlobalKey<CustomRefreshIndicatorState>();

    AppRouter() {
      final String initialLocation = Routes.hub.path;

      routes = GoRouter(
        navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
        initialLocation: initialLocation,
        refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(authBloc.stream),
        redirect: (context, state) {
          final accessToken = authBloc.state.accessToken;
          if (accessToken?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
            if (state.uri.toString() == Routes.welcome.path) {
              return Routes.hub.path;
            }
          } else {
            if (state.uri.toString() == Routes.hub.path) {
              return Routes.welcome.path;
            }
          }
          return null;
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
            name: Routes.welcome.name,
            path: Routes.welcome.path,
            builder: (context, state) => const Welcome(),
            routes: [
              StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
                parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
                builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
                  return navigationShell;
                },
                branches: [
                  StatefulShellBranch(
                    navigatorKey:
                        GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'welcomeNavigator'),
                    routes: [
                      GoRoute(
                        name: Routes.login.name,
                        path: Routes.login.name,
                        builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  StatefulShellBranch(
                    navigatorKey: createAccountNavigatorKey,
                    routes: [
                      GoRoute(
                        name: Routes.createaccount.name,
                        path: Routes.createaccount.name,
                        builder: (context, state) => const CreateAccount(),
                        routes: [
                          GoRoute(
                            name: Routes.simpleimageeditor.name,
                            path: Routes.simpleimageeditor.name,
                            parentNavigatorKey: createAccountNavigatorKey,
                            builder: (context, state) {
                              Map<String, Object> args =
                                  state.extra as Map<String, Object>;
                              final assets = args['assetsBloc'] as AssetsBloc;
                              final selected =
                                  args['imageBloc'] as SelectedAssetBloc;

                              return SimpleImageEditor(
                                assetsBloc: assets,
                                selectedAssetBloc: selected,
                              );
                            },
                            routes: [
                              GoRoute(
                                name: Routes.mycropeditor.name,
                                path: Routes.mycropeditor.name,
                                builder: (context, state) {
                                  Map<String, Object> args =
                                      state.extra as Map<String, Object>;
                                  final imageBloc =
                                      args['image_bloc'] as SelectedAssetBloc;
                                  return MyCropEditor(imageBloc: imageBloc);
                                },
                              ),
                              GoRoute(
                                name: Routes.myfiltereditor.name,
                                path: Routes.myfiltereditor.name,
                                builder: (context, state) {
                                  Map<String, Object> args =
                                      state.extra as Map<String, Object>;
                                  final imageBloc =
                                      args['image_bloc'] as SelectedAssetBloc;
                                  final transformations =
                                      args['transformations'] as TransformConfigs;
                                  return MyFilterEditor(
                                      transformations: transformations,
                                      imageBloc: imageBloc);
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
            parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
            builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
              return DashboardScreen(key: state.pageKey, child: navigationShell);
            },
            branches: [
              StatefulShellBranch(
                navigatorKey:
                    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'hubNavigator'),
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    name: Routes.hub.name,
                    path: Routes.hub.path,
                    builder: (context, state) => const Hub(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              StatefulShellBranch(
                navigatorKey:
                    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'feedNavigator'),
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    name: Routes.feed.name,
                    path: Routes.feed.path,
                    builder: (context, state) => const Feed(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              StatefulShellBranch(
                navigatorKey:
                    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'searchNavigator'),
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    name: Routes.search.name,
                    path: Routes.search.path,
                    builder: (context, state) => const Search(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              StatefulShellBranch(
                navigatorKey:
                    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'mapaNavigator'),
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    name: Routes.mapa.name,
                    path: Routes.mapa.path,
                    builder: (context, state) => const Mapa(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  class GoRouterRefreshStream extends ChangeNotifier {
    GoRouterRefreshStream(Stream<dynamic> stream) {
      notifyListeners();
      _subscription = stream.asBroadcastStream().listen(
            (dynamic _) => notifyListeners(),
          );
    }
    late final StreamSubscription<dynamic> _subscription;
    @override
    void dispose() {
      _subscription.cancel();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }

I tried everything possible. Documentation isnt very detailed unfortunately.
I want to properly do a popuntil feature while preserving the routes state when coming back

Since goRouter is declarative routing approach the pages are rebuilt resulting in the state being lost thus you want ensure that the pages remain in the memory or preserve the state of your widgets. For the popUntil feature you might want to extend the GoRouter class as explained in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77291669/19795666
Just being based on your hierarchy you can do something like(am avoiding the extra/params for simplicity):
class AppRouter {
  static final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        name: 'welcome',
        builder: (context, state) => const WelcomePage(),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: 'login',
            name: 'login',
            builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: 'createaccount',
            name: 'createaccount',
            builder: (context, state) => CreateAccountPage(),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: 'simpleimageeditor',
                name: 'simpleimageeditor',
                builder: (context, state) => const SimpleImageEditorPage(),
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'mycropeditor',
                    name: 'mycropeditor',
                    builder: (context, state) => const MyCropEditorPage(),
                  ),
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'myfiltereditor',
                    name: 'myfiltereditor',
                    builder: (context, state) => const MyFilterEditorPage(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}

extension GoRouterExtension on GoRouter {
  void popUntilPath(String ancestorPath) {
    while (routerDelegate.currentConfiguration.matches.last.matchedLocation != ancestorPath) {
      if (!canPop()) {
        return;
      }
      pop();
    }
  }
}

Then for preserving the state of your widget you can use  StatefulWidget and AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin /OR may use change notifiers here to set the values
class CreateAccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateAccountPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateAccountPage> createState() => _CreateAccountPageState();
}

class _CreateAccountPageState extends State<CreateAccountPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);//make sure to call this and override the wantKeepAlive to true
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Create Account')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Text('Create Account Page'),
            TextField(
              controller: controller,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.pushNamed('simpleimageeditor');
              },
              child: const Text('Go to Simple Image Editor'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

hierarchy call as:
  const WelcomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Welcome')),
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context.pushNamed('login');
        },
        child: const Text('Login Page'),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Login')),
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context.pushNamed('createaccount');
        },
        child: const Text('Create Account Page'),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class CreateAccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateAccountPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateAccountPage> createState() => _CreateAccountPageState();
}

class _CreateAccountPageState extends State<CreateAccountPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Create Account')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Text('Create Account Page'),
            TextField(
              controller: controller,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.pushNamed('simpleimageeditor');
                // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SimpleImageEditorPage()));
              },
              child: const Text('Go to Simple Image Editor'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class SimpleImageEditorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SimpleImageEditorPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Simple Image Editor')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  context.pushNamed('mycropeditor');
                },
                child: const Text('Go to crop Editor'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCropEditorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCropEditorPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Crop Editor')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            context.pushNamed('myfiltereditor');
          },
          child: const Text('Filter Editor'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyFilterEditorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyFilterEditorPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Filter Editor')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            GoRouter.of(context).popUntilPath('/createaccount');
          },
          child: const Text('Back to Create Account'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thank you for your response. I knew about that mixin but didn’t remember to use in this case. I have 2 questions: 1) in order to preserve a route state am I not suppose to do that logic using keys or statefulshellroute in the GoRouter setup? Is the way that you showed me the official way of doing it according to go_router good practices?

regarding the pop until I heard that extension works well but that the “good” way of doing it was to create child routes structure and then call go or goNamed and that would do a popuntil. I am referring to the link you send Acácio response


And one last question but what is the porpuse of shellroute? Is to construct a bottom nav bar which doesn’t keep the state of the routes? And statefullshellroute is the same but keeps the state? Am I not suppose to use any of those classes?
